# Connect to database remotely from another server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to connect a website A  in a server A to a mysql database B in a server B (cpanel).  I'm using this code for my connection:

`$myServer = "host_B";
$myUsername = "user_database_B";
$myPassword = "pass_database_B";
$myDatabase = "name_database_B";`

`$con = mysqli_connect($myServer,$myUsername,$myPassword );`

I'm getting this error: "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.​"

I also have the port 3306 opened and in server B I have allowed the ip of the website A for remote connections to the database.

I'm just wondering if you can help me and give me ideas what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect` takes four parameters. You forgot to include the database name `$myDatabase`

```
$con = mysqli_connect($myServer, $myUsername, $myPassword, $myDatabase);
```

Comment: I forgot to say I do this later: `mysql_select_db($myDatabase, $con);`

Comment: @HenryAlpacaSalas do that later? You cannot connect to your database without the database name. Do not suppose that you can connect without the database name because you can't. You need it man when using `mysqli_connect function`. That's why it's throwing an error

Comment: The asker is correct here. You do not need to specify a database on connection to the server, instead it will just use the default.

Comment: @HenryAlpacaSalas Enter the correct sql server to avoid such an error

Comment: Yeah using the database later works fine. The problem is in the connection line. I cannot connect to the server for some reason. I tried using the IP and the hostname(www.example.com) in the server variable. Now I'm wondering what is the hostname of the mysqldatabase allocated on the server. Is the same as the IP of the website? I read is the same... But I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @JohnRobertson How can I know what is my mysql server?. I'm using the IP address of the server, but I'm not sure is the same of the database in MySQL.